# How to push to an array index that does not yet exist

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to create objects sets in an array, and create a new set if the item does not yet exist.

The data structure is like

```
[
  {
    "order": orderData,
    "items": itemData
  }, {
    "order": orderData,
    "items": itemData
  }
]
```

However, when trying to create a new array index on-the-fly and push to it, I get the following error:

> Cannot set property 'items' of undefined

In this case, `setNo = 2`, but `this.cart[2]` is not yet instantiated.

```
this.cart[setNo]['items'].push(items);
```

How do I initialize this index so that it can be pushed to on-the-fly?

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn this logic gave me the same error.

Comment: create the array and proccesses it first. then `this.cart[setNo]["items"] = myArrayThatIsAlreadyProccessed`

Comment: Oops sorry, misread. You need to instantiate the object something like this: `if(!this.cart[setNo]) this.cart[setNo] = { order: orderData, items: [] }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably, you need to check first:

```
if (!this.cart[setNo]) {
   this.cart[setNo] = {order: {}, items: []};
} 
this.cart[setNo]['items'].push(item);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the `cart[setNo]` doesn't exist set it object with `items` property

```
if(!this.cart[setNo]) cart[setNo] = {items:[]};
this.cart[setNo]['items'].push(items)
```

Comment: So `if (!this.cart[setNo]) this.cart[setNo] = {}; this.cart[setNo]['items'].push(items)` worked.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to check and add as well:

```js
let arr = [
  { "order": {}, "items": [] }, 
  { "order": {}, "items": [] }
], setNo = 2

arr[setNo] 
  ? arr[setNo]['items'].push(1) 
  : (arr[setNo] = { order: {}, items: [] })['items'].push(1)
 
console.log(arr)
```